# Adding multiple Json node into one Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to create Json Structure like the below one

```
{
  "properties": {
    "a": {
        "b": 1,
        "c": "2",
        "d": 3,
        "e": 4
    },
    "f": {
        "g": 5,
        "h": "6",
        "i": 7,
        "j": 8
    }
  }
}
```

but I could not.

I have written following code

```
for(Annotation a : annotationList) {
    ObjectNode objectNode1 = readAnnotation(a);
    String name= getName(key);
    objectNode.putPOJO(name, objectNode1);
    propertiesObjectNode.put("properties", objectNode1);
}
```

to create a JSON but eventually i have only one node in properties.

I got following Json

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "f" : {
      "g" : 5,
      "h" : "6",
      "i" : 7,
      "j" : 8
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make objectNode1 a list and add all the readAnnotations to that before putting it in propertiesObjectNode and creating json. Probably right now the second annotation is the only one getting added to properties.

Comment: thats possible but i dont want to add as list.

Comment: You're overwriting your `properties` item by calling `propertiesObjectNode.put("properties", whatever)` once per annotation. Create the `properties` item first, then set one of its fields for each annotation?

Comment: You do realize that properties object in JSON is a JSONArray and not a JSONObject and for it to be able to store multiple values you need to have a collection object in your POJO and not a single object.

Comment: The JSON cannot be generated incrementally as you are trying. You need to create a valid POJO object with all the values in it and convert it to JSON in one go. Therefore you need to store all the annotations in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
propertiesObjectNode.put("properties", objectNode1);
```

This line is inside a for loop, so you are overwriting it with each iteration. At the end you are left with just 1 node which was a result of last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm off base here, but if you are using Jackson, why not use the ObjectMapper class. It will convert a POJO to JSON.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);
```

If you wanted to setup something like you have, jackson can take the map and output the json version.

You would have something like:

```
Map<String, Object> a = new HashMap<String, Object>();
a.put("b", 1);
a.put("c", "2");

Map<String, Object> f = new HashMap<String, Object>();
f.put("g", 5);
f.put("h", "6");

Map<String, Object> propWrapper = new HashMap<String, Object>();
propWrapper.put("a", a)
propWrapper.put("f", f)

Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("properties", props);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(props);
```

And that should output the structure you're looking for. It would be better to use your own POJO to get a more meaning full structure, but this should provide an idea.